# Android list pagination

Tags: lists, android, pagination, cursor

I need to do paginated list of items in android application.

What are the best practices to do this?

I use cursor loader to get data from content provider(cache). If the data is expired the provider initiates loading data from web.

Update: Concreting question: What is the best way to implement a paginated list (load more button, endless list or something else)?

Comment: You need to make your question more specific.  "Is X a good idea?".  Not "what are all the good ideas for Y?"

Comment: If you're asking about infinite scrolling (an "endless list") it sounds more like you're asking "How should I display a list of content on android" rather than about pagination in particular, unless explicit pages are a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends very much on your application.  Each method has strengths and weaknesses, so you need to weigh up each one and decide from there.

A paginated list is **easy to navigate to a specific point**, and would probable be best where you have many items and someone is likely to need to jump to a specific one.

Infinite scroll is good for a simple interface where it is most likely that someone will want to see the earlier items, or where there aren't many items in the first place.  Think of a blog here.

Clicking to show more is best in similar situation to infinite scroll, but where **bandwidth is an issue**.  I only have to load up what I want to load up that way, but I have to click another button.  You need to decide which will be more important or, even better, ask your customers.

---

I am facing a similar issue in an app I'm working on, and my current solution is to use a slider both for navigation and positional information.  I have yet to test this out with customers, but I think the idea has merit.

[image]